# Input format of file for d2i_RSAPublicKey_fp

Tags: openssl

I am trying to run the code as follow:

RSA *aikRsa;
aikRsa = d2i_RSAPublicKey_fp(fp, NULL);

But the return is always NULL. I am doubting whether the input file fp's format is correct. So, is there anyone know what kind of format should the file fp be? Could you give me a example?

Comment: Your code seems fine provided that file should contain valid RSA public key. Please see what ERR_error_string_n says.

Comment: In case you are reading a X.509 certificate, read it first in X.509 structure and then extract public key from it.